# ¿Por qué tengo este error en la lectura de una QSqlQuery?

Tags: c++, datatables, sql, sqlite, qt

En mi programa de Qt tengo un `String`para insertar ciertos datos en una base de datos SQLite. La parte de código donde se ejecuta defino mi `QString`y se ejecuta la `QSqlquery` es la siguiente:

```
    qDebug()<<"Mi id del clone"<<myClonedSetupID;
    qDebug()<<"Mi id del original"<<cloneFromId;
    QString queryStr;
    QSqlQuery query;
    queryStr=QString("INSERT INTO SetupEvaluationMagnitudes (Setup_ID, AssessmentGroup, Assessment, AssessmentQuantity, Selection) "
                     "SELECT '%1',AssessmentGroup,Assessment,AssessmentQuantity, Selection "
                     "FROM SetupEvaluationMagnitudes WHERE Setup_ID = '%2' ").arg(myClonedSetupID,cloneFromId);
    qDebug()<<queryStr;
    if(!query.exec(queryStr)){
        qDebug()<<"Error clonning"<<query.lastError();
    }
```

Pues bien, lo que ocurre al ejecutarlo, que lo veo gracias a los qDebug(), es lo siguiente:

```
Mi id del clone 19
Mi id del original 11
"INSERT INTO SetupEvaluationMagnitudes (Setup_ID, AssessmentGroup, Assessment, AssessmentQuantity, Selection) 
SELECT '         19',AssessmentGroup,Assessment,AssessmentQuantity, Selection 
FROM SetupEvaluationMagnitudes 
WHERE Setup_ID = '%2' "
```

Como se puede ver el error es que el `myClonedSetupID`si que lo coge bien y pone el id del clone que corresponde (poniendo 19 en el lugar del `%1`), pero en el `cloneFromId`no me coge el id original (11 en este caso) y sigue poniendo `%2`.

Nota: tanto `myClonedSetupID`como `cloneFromId`son tipo `int`.

**¿Alguna idea de porque puede ser? ¿  Por qué me coge uno bien y otro no?**

Comment: ¿ Tipos de `myClonedSetupID` y `cloneFromId` ?

Comment: Los dos son tipo `int`, perdón que se me ha olvidado ponerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible hacer lo que pretendes. [`QString.arg( )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) tiene muchas sobrecargas ... pero ninguna *reemplaza* a la vez **2 `int`**.

Lo mas simple, creo que es llamar a `arg( )` 2 veces:

```
queryStr = QString("INSERT INTO SetupEvaluationMagnitudes (Setup_ID, AssessmentGroup, Assessment, AssessmentQuantity, Selection) "
                     "SELECT '%1',AssessmentGroup,Assessment,AssessmentQuantity, Selection "
                     "FROM SetupEvaluationMagnitudes WHERE Setup_ID = '%2' ").arg( myClonedSetupID ).arg( cloneFromId );
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me ha resuelto la duda 100%.